# Custom validator on a list box?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I need to verify that my list box is not empty before the user is able to proceed to the next page. I am just not sure how to implement the custom validator. Below is what I have so far:

```
Protected Sub cmdNext_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) _
    Handles cmdNext.Click

    If StateDropDown.Text = "Select...." Then
        Dim message As String = "Please select a state"
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
        sb.Append("alert('")
        sb.Append(message)
        sb.Append("')};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", _
                                               sb.ToString())

        'ElseIf NPIListbox.Text = "" Then
        '    Dim message As String = "Please select a Doctor"
        '    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        '    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        '    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
        '    sb.Append("alert('")
        '    sb.Append(message)
        '    sb.Append("')};")
        '    sb.Append("</script>")
        '    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", _
        '                                           sb.ToString())
    Else
        Dim data As String = HiddenOptions.Value.TrimEnd(","c)
        Session("NPIList") = data
        Response.Redirect("~/frmDescriptionofNature.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, _
    ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) _
    Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate

    args.IsValid = NPIListbox.Items.Count > 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code it will work

```
    Protected Sub CustomValidator2_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As        System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator2.ServerValidate  
    args.IsValid = False  
    For Each a As ListItem In ListBox1.Items  
        If a.Selected Then  
            args.IsValid = True  
            Exit For  
        End If  
    Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and even when the list box is populated the args.value.length is always 0?

Comment: For some reason, it is skipping over the for each statement like there isnt anything in the list box but there is. Keep in mind the user will not be selecting any item in the list box. Its just a list of numbers I carry over to the next page